# Netcat udp listener upon boot

Tags: boot

My goal is open a UDP listener on port 5555 upon booting my device. It's suppose to be looking for a specific message that will tell it to do some updates. I have a service started upon boot that has a shell script the run net cat. I have cross compiled netcat to run on my machine.

My init.rc has something along the lines:

```
service update /system/bin/update.sh
    class core
    critical
```

My update script is:

```
netcat -luvv -p 5555 2>&1 | while read cmd params; do
case $cmd in
   #do stuff
esac
done
```

So in this, my service does get started, and netcat begins. Only issue is it's not recieving any messages I'm trying to send out. Also, if I try to send out any messages manually through netcat, like echo hello | netcat -u localhost 5555, it's not sending out any bytes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.